# How should the ViewModel communicate with the Model so that both are synchronised

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm

In an MVVM design, how should the `ViewModel` communicate with the `Model` so that both are synchronised?

From what I have read so far, most articles show that since the `ViewModel` wraps the `Model`, the `ViewModel` can access the `Model` directly. In this case, the `ViewModel` can directly retrieve and update data on the `Model`.

However, what happens if some data in the `Model` gets updated not through the `ViewModel`? In this case, since the `ViewModel` isn't observing or data bound to the `Model`, the `ViewModel` will not be aware that data in the `Model` has been changed externally (not from the ViewModel itself) or when the `Model` interacts with other Models and had its data changed, and the `ViewModel` will not inform the `View`.

So, how should the `ViewModel` communicate with the `Model` so that both are synchronised?

Answer (score 2):

The model should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The ViewModel can then subscribe to the according events and fire its own PropertyChanged notification on changes of the model, so that the view gets updated.

> The model classes typically provide property and collection change notification events through the **INotifyPropertyChanged** and **INotifyCollectionChanged** interfaces. This allows them to be easily data bound in the view. Model classes that represent collections of objects typically derive from the **ObservableCollection** class.

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28PandP.40%29.aspx

In order to not mess up your models (and anything else) with the INotifyChanged stuff, I recommend using the *Notify Property Weaver Extension*: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd351303-db8c-4771-9b22-5e51524fccd3

Answer (score 0):

> what happens if some data in the Model gets updated not through the ViewModel

if thats the case and if you want that this updates to be publish outside the model - your model simply has to implement something to do so (eg. Events)

your viewmodel can then simply subscribe to this event and notify the view.

Comment: Would this end up to become an anti-pattern and accumulate a mess to the MVVM design?

Comment: why should this end up to become an anti-pattern or a mess?